# Setting a default selection in a select menu in JQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, select-menu

I'm trying to set the default selection in a select menu in JQuery mobile. The docs have this:

```
   var myselect = $("select#foo");
   myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
   myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

Which I added right underneath where I create the menu, but then when I run the code I get this error:

> throw "cannot call methods on " + name + " prior to initialization; " +
>   "attempted to call method '" + options + "'";

Not sure what to do at this point...

Comment: The problem is you're manipulating objects that don't exist yet.  Did the modified example I provided (binding the code to the pagecreate even of the containing page) solve your error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to manipulate DOM objects with javascript that haven't loaded yet.  Move the javascript past the form you're trying to manipulate, or more your code into a function that executes on document load.

For example:

```
$('#PAGE').live('pagecreate',function(event){
    var myselect = $("select#foo");
    myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
    myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
});
```

where `PAGE` is the id of the page you're loading that contains the menu you want to manipulate.

---

EDIT:

I updated the example to use the JQuery Mobile pagecreate event based on jinyuan's comment regarding [JQuery Mobile events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/#/test/docs/api/events.html).

Comment: document.ready doesn't work for jqm.
use .live() to bind event such as 'pageshow,pagehide'
check the demo for the list of events.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/#/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: position of JS related to markup tells you very little, almost nothing about when those are "live"

Answer (score 3):

As jQuery function:

```
$.fn.jqmSelectedIndex = function(index){
    var self = $(this)
    self
        .prop('selectedIndex', index)
    .selectmenu("refresh");

    return self;
}

$("select#foo").jqmSelectedIndex(3);
```

This isn't validated but works.

Answer (score 1):

it works. maybe you might want to provide more details.

http://jsbin.com/ekayu3/2